# How to get imported class to change attribute of main.py label stylesheet

Tags: python-3.x, class, user-interface, button, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 to create a gui, defining a `buttons` class in a separate .py file and importing it, then trying to use a `method` from my `buttons` class to change the color of a label in my `Ui_MainWindow` which is my gui class in main.py

I have isolated this code from a larger project which outlines what I am attempting to accomplish.

Here is my buttons class which is saved and imported as buttons:

```py
class buttons(object):
    def __init__(self, Ui_MainWindow):
        print('creating buttons object')

    def func(self):
        Ui_MainWindow.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
```

Here is my main.py with my Ui_MainWindow class which constructs the gui:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import buttons

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(311, 228)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")


        # Push button created
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: (btn_obj.func()))
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 70, 131, 81))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 50, 121, 101))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 4);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 311, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        # CREATE A BUTTONS OBJECT SO WE CAN CALL ITS METHOD
        btn_obj = buttons.buttons(self)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is throwing the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Gaming\Google Drive\Code\Python\help\main.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: (btn_obj.func()))
  File "c:\Users\Gaming\Google Drive\Code\Python\help\buttons.py", line 6, in func
    Ui_MainWindow.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
NameError: name 'Ui_MainWindow' is not defined
```

If I understand correctly, since the label in question is an attribute of a `Ui_MainWindow` object, and not the class itself it is unable to be changed with my current code. I am hoping someone could show/tell me the proper way to implement this sort of thing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Ui_MainWindow` is a **class** created by the output of a pyuic command. Please learn how to properly use UI files by following the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), and also do some research and studying on what are and how do classes and instances work.

Comment: But I know what the `Ui_MainWindow ` class is, I am trying to edit an attribute of the class
and don't know if I need to make that attribute `label` a global variable or what to change its style sheet from another class. If you know how to do that, please link me to a resource so I can learn too. Thank you.

Comment: 1. Do **not** use globals. 2. You should not use the same name of a class for a variable that refers to an instance (`Ui_MainWindow`). 3. Setting the stylesheet from a lambda that gets a reference to an external object to get to the label by accessing the UI is unnecessarily convoluted as much as prone to bugs (like yours). Instead of trying to implement too complex systems, learn how to use the proper classes and instances, so, as I said: 4. Do **NOT** edit pyuic files, as it almost always creates just problems and confusion (like in your case, since you're confusing a class and an instance).

Comment: " 4. Do NOT edit pyuic files, as it almost always creates just problems and confusion (like in your case, since you're confusing a class and an instance)."

That's not because I edited a pyuic file friend, it is because I am a beginner. Thanks for all your useful input though. I solved my problem from someone in the Python discord who just taught me how to do it instead of telling me to go learn it without giving me any resource to go learn it from.

Comment: any resource? I gave you a *very important* link in my first comment. Have you read it? Did you understand its contents? If you thought StackOverflow was a tutorial or howto website, I'm sorry but you're mistaken, and I suggest you to go through the [tour]. We provide answers to specific problems, your question had general issues (including those I linked), and we couldn't answer any question like this, since this is **not** how StackOverflow works: unfocused questions and/or with too many issues, just don't get answers or are closed. You may not like it, but that's how it is.

Comment: That said: 1. Be careful with random discord "helpers" (really, there's a lot of *bad* coders there that just pretend to be some "professionals" - not that here don't have any, but at least there's some quality "peer review"), and remember that coding is not "someone taught me how to do it", but "learning to understand how to do it on your own". Lots of those people just "taught" what to do (and that's not learning, it's just imitating without understanding). Programming is ALL about learning how to solve problems, including knowing how to do your learning.

Comment: 2. Yes, you faced your problem because you're a beginner (and nobody would ever blame you for that), but **ALSO** because you edited those files (being a beginner doesn't mean you should ignore your mistakes just because you did them as a beginner). There's a warning in the header of those files, and if you've a pretty updated PyQt version (since 5.13, if I'm not mistaken), that warning is also very clear: you should *not* edit them unless you *really* know what you're doing. Have you done more research on classes/instances, as suggested? Did you understand what was the problem you created?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change:

```
class buttons(object):
def __init__(self, Ui_MainWindow):
    print('creating buttons object')

def func(self):
    Ui_MainWindow.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
```

To:

```
class buttons(object):
    def __init__(self, Ui_MainWindow):
        print('creating buttons object')
        self.Ui_MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow
    def func(self):
        self.Ui_MainWindow.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
```

Comment: This was downvoted but it solved my problem to a T with no unexpected results so I am going to except it.

Comment: Please check the syntax and indentation, and remember that class names should always begin with uppercase letters (read more about these *important* aspects on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).